# ffmpeg remove multiple segments from a video rotate and crop video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

ffmpeg  remove multiple segments from a video rotate and crop video

I have a video of 2 min 25 seconds , i want to remove part from 10 second to 16 second and 20 second to 26 second and rotate video and crop it

I am trying this command

```
 "-y", "-i", j,
                      "-filter_complex",
                        "[0:v]trim=start=10:end=16,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];  " +
                                "[0:v]trim=start=20:end=26,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; " +
                                "[0:a]atrim=start=10:end=16,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[c]; " +
                                "[0:a]atrim=start=20:end=26,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; " +
                                "[a][c][b][d]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[e][f],"+
                                "crop=" + 40 + ":" + 20 + ":" + 100 + ":" + 100,"+
                                "transpose=1", "-map", "'[e]'" ,"-map",
                        "'[f]'", "-preset", "ultrafast",out
```

what is the correct command to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the filtering, use

```
ffmpeg -y -i in
 -filter_complex,
       "[0:v]select='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,26))',setpts=N/30/TB,crop=40:20:100:100,transpose=1[v];
        [0:a]aselect='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,26))',asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]"
 -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -b:v 2097k -r 60 -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4
```

(Drop the transpose filter if the video comes out rotated. It's because ffmpeg is autorotating the video beforehand.

The trim filter keeps the specified segment **in** and removes everything else. You want to do the reverse. That can also be done with multiple trim filters, but a single select filter is more convenient.

Comment: i tried follwoing command "-y", "-i", j,
                        "filter_complex",
                                "[0:v]select='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,26))',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS," + "crop=40:20:100:100,transpose=1[v];" + "0:a]aselect='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,26))',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a]","-map", "'[e]'", "-map","'[f]'", "-preset", "ultrafast", out, as you suggested, I am getting error Metadata:creation_time   : 2017-11-01 17:32:41handler_name    : SoundHandle[NULL @ 0xac915f90] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'filter_complex'

Comment: You skipped the `-` in `-filter_complex`.

Comment: sorry newbie error still learning about ffmpeg, your guidance is helpful

Comment: the command is executed, but i still get only the rotated video, I must not framed the question correctly, what i want to do is remove that part of video between seconds 10 and 16 , and create a new video, which should not have these parts, instead i get the same 2 min 25 sec video, it should be without those 6 seconds how can that be done

Comment: Did you map [v] and [a] and remove [e] and [f]?

Comment: And if you're using a recent version of ffmpeg, ffmpeg will autorotate and you can drop the `transpose=1`,

Comment: this is the command I am trying  "-y", "-i", j,"-filter_complex","[0:v]select='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,26))',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS," +"crop=" + (videocropRight - videocropLeft) + ":"+ (videocropBottom - videocroptop) + "" +":" + videocropLeft + ":" + videocroptop + ",transpose=1[v];""-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4",
"-preset", "ultrafast", out

Comment: this command works as required, but the new video still has the same duration, ie , when we play the video, it shows 2 min 25 seconds , but it jumps directly from second 10 to 16 and from 20 to 26, while that part is removed , the video duration is not edited , is there a way to do that?

Comment: Share the full log.

Comment: I have added another question may be i have not framed this question correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070936/ffmpeg-remove-part-of-video-crop-rotate-video

Comment: No, it's clear, your video reports a weird FPS. Try edited command.

Comment: can you share a command using  trim filters, I am still having some issues

Comment: the new comand you have share still does not work, it takes too long to execute even with  a 6  second video, I have tried with multiple videos, for all the (old) commands does execute,ie it removes the required part but the duration of the video doesnot change,  when we check the duration that (ANY) mediaplayer displays is the original duration, whereas it should be without the duration that has been removed, can you help me with that I have been trying for a long time

Comment: direct link for what? video? http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi

Comment: That's the 480p version.

Comment: i have tried on multiple video, please try on the 480 p version the other video downloaded earlier, i dont know what happened now, i have tried on this 480 p video also, it is the same result i removed part from 15 sec to 8 mins , but the video that we get is still 9 mins 56 sec long , middle portion is skipped jumps from 15 sec directly to 8 mins